# Frama-c fails to parse an ACSL manual example list_length involving a pattern matching construct

Tags: frama-c, formal-verification

On the following function definition (list.c):

```
//@ type list<A> = Nil | Cons(A,list<A>);

/*@ logic integer list_length<A>(list<A> l) = 
  @ \match l {
  @   case Nil : 0
  @   case Cons(h,t) : 1 + list_length(tail)
  @ };
*/
```

frama-c fails with the message:

```
$ frama-c -wp -wp-rte list.c

[jessie3] Loading Why3 configuration...
[jessie3] Why3 environment loaded.
[jessie3] Loading Why3 theories...
[jessie3] Loading Why3 modules...
[kernel] Parsing FRAMAC_SHARE/libc/__fc_builtin_for_normalization.i (no preprocessing)
[kernel] Parsing list.c (with preprocessing)
list.c:4:[kernel] user error: unexpected token 'l'
[kernel] user error: stopping on file "list.c" that has errors. Add '-kernel-msg-key pp'
                     for preprocessing command.
[kernel] Frama-C aborted: invalid user input.
```

The example is taken directly from the [ACSL manual](http://frama-c.com/download/acsl.pdf).
Why does it have troubles associating `l` with the only parameter of the function?

P.S. I use frama-c version: Sodium-20150201

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pattern matching is not supported in the current implementation of Frama-C. In order to check whether a specific ACSL feature is supported by the kernel (which does not always mean that your favorite plug-in will handle it), refer to the [ACSL implementation manual](http://frama-c.com/download/frama-c-acsl-implementation.pdf). As mentioned in the intro of the manual, every entry appearing in red is unsupported by the current version of Frama-C.